# Loop to get value of line edit; error in code

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to search line edits on a UI and put the contents of certain line edits into a list. The line edits I am searching for have object names like "equity1, equity2, equity3, ....."  and I want to put each of these into list ename in same order.

I am getting an error with my code, specifically the line:

```
ename[p-1] = child.objectName().text()
```

I think there is a syntax error.

```
p = 1
for child in self.ui.frame_23.findChildren(QLineEdit):
    if child.objectName() == "equity" + str(p):
        ename[p-1] = child.objectName().text()
        p += 1
```

Comment: provide a [mre] and show complete error message

Comment: Probably want `ename[p-1] = child.text()`. objectName() is already a string, doesn't have a text() method, and is not the contents of the line edit.

Comment: Typo: change `child.objectName().text()` to `child.text()`

Comment: Works. Thanks to all.